# How to show Tukey's Lemma proves Zorn's lemma?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I heard that Zorn's lemma is equivalent to [Tukey's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller%E2%80%93Tukey_lemma).
 Now I've proved that Zorn's lemma implies that Tukey's lemma but I cannot prove that Tukey's lemma implies Zorn's lemma. How to show this?

Comment: This question is somewhat related: [Tukey's lemma by axiom of choice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135655/tukeys-lemma-by-axiom-of-choice).

Answer (score 5):

You’re given a partial order $\langle P,\le\rangle$ in which every chain has an upper bound, and you want to show that $P$ has a maximal element. To apply Tukey’s lemma, you need to find a family $\mathscr{F}$ of finite character such that a maximal element of $\mathscr{F}$ with respect to $\subseteq$ will somehow give you a maximal element of $P$ with respect to $\le$. Since your hypothesis on $P$ involves chains, it’s reasonable to look for some family connected with them. As it happens, the simplest one works: let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of chains in $P$.

1. Show that $\mathscr{C}$ has finite character.

Let $C$ be a $\subseteq$-maximal element of $\mathscr{C}$. $C$ is a chain in $P$, so it has an upper bound $p$.

1. Show that $p\in C$.
2. Conclude that $p$ is a $\le$-maximal element of $P$.

Comment: Hausdorff maximal principle naturally appears as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 3):

Assume Tukey's lemma holds. Suppose that $(P,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound.

Now consider $\mathcal F$ to be the collection of all chains in $P$. To see that $\mathcal F$ has a finite character recall that every finite subset of a chain is a chain, and that if $B\subseteq P$ is *not* a chain then there is a finite subset witnessing that.

Now $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element $C$, which is a chain and therefore has an upper bound $p$. By the maximality of $C$ we have that $p\in C$ and that $p$ is maximal.

Comment: Why should $p \in C$, $p$ need not even be a chain right? (Obviously, I'm missing something here)

Comment: $p$ is not a chain, it's an element of $P$. But because $C$ is a maximal chain it has an upper bound in $P$, call it $p$, but by the maximality of $C$, $p\in C$ otherwise $C\cup\{p\}$ is a strictly larger chain. But an upper bound of a chain that is in the chain is a maximum there, and again by maximality of $C$ it is a maximal element of $P$.

Comment: Thanks! Immediately after I typed the comment, I understood why:)

Comment: "But an upper bound of a chain that is in the chain is a maximum there, and again by maximality of C it is a maximal element of P." Why is this obvious? Does this use Hausdorff maximal principle as someone commented above?

Comment: No, we're not using Hausdorff's maximality principle. We used Tukey's lemma to produce a maximal chain. An upper bound of a maximal chain is a maximal element, that's pretty obvious, yes, spend some time mulling it over and if you can't see why write the definitions down.

Comment: Suppose not. Then there is some $x \neq p$ such that $x \geq p$. Then, $x \notin C$ as $p$ is the upper bound. So, we can consider $C \cup {x}$ which is a chain since the partial order is transitive. Clearly, this new set is a maximal element of set of chains which is a contradiction. I guess this works.

Comment: " every finite subset of a chain is a chain," Isn't every subset of a chain a chain?

Comment: @Porky: Yes, and in particular, finite subsets, which is what the Teichmüller–Tukey Lemma is concerned with.